# I need to get the patient id from the maximum Date of time arrived

Tags: mysql

I need to get the patient_id from the Maximum Date of Time_arrived

Time_Arrived Greater than '01-01-2016'

Sample

```
    Patien_ID  TIME_ARRIVED
    1234       01-01-2013
    1234       01-02-2014
    1235       01-02-2014
    1235       01-02-2015 
    1236       01-02-2015
    1236       01-03-2016
    1237       01-03-2015
    1237       01-04-2016
```

RESULT MUST BE

```
Patient_id
1236
1237
```

Comment: Why 1236 and 1237 both are in result? Since 1-4-2016 is the maximum date, shouldn't only 1237 be the result?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough

Comment: Store dates as dates

Comment: output should be 1237 only.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like time_arrived is a date column (not a datetime) then you can use this query:

```
select distinct patient_id
from patients
where time_arrived>='2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your time_arrived in MySQl date format i.e. 'yyyy-mm-dd' using below function :

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `db_name`$$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `strtotime`$$

CREATE FUNCTION `strtotime`(input_string VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
BEGIN

DECLARE var_upd_str VARCHAR(50);


IF(input_string LIKE '%-%-%' AND input_string NOT LIKE '%-%-%-%') THEN

SET var_upd_str= CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_string,'-',-1),'-',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_string,'-',-2),'-',1),'-',SUBSTRING_INDEX(input_string,'-',1));

END IF;

RETURN var_upd_str;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

update your table:-

```
UPDATE patient SET time_arrived=strtotime(time_arrived);

ALTER TABLE patient CHANGE time_arrived time_arrived DATE NOT NULL;
```

If you want patient id from maximum time arrived and time arrived should be greater than OR equqls to '2016-01-01':

```
SELECT patient_id FROM patient WHERE time_arrived=(SELECT MAX(time_arrived) AS date_arr  FROM patient) AND time_arrived>='2016-01-01';
```

If you want patient id for which arrival time should be greater than OR equals to '2016-01-01':

```
SELECT patient_id FROM patient WHERE  time_arrived>='2016-01-01';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out its simple

select patient_id from patients order by time_arrived desc limit 2

Here limit will show 2 results and desc will show the date in descending order of time arrived column data.